# How do I import an Excel file into IDEA using IDEAScript?

Tags: ideascript

I would like to import a file called Sales.xlsx into IDEA.  How can I do this using IDEAScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import the file using the code below.  This code assumes that you are importing one sheet from the excel file and that it's name is Sales.

```
Sub Main
  Call ImportExcel("Sales.xlsx", "Sales")
End Sub

Sub ImportExcel(FileName As String, SheetName As String)
  Dim dbName As String  

  dbName = Client.LocateInputFile(FileName)
  Set task = Client.GetImportTask("ImportExcel")
  task.FileToImport = dbName
  task.SheetToImport = SheetName
  task.OutputFilePrefix = "Excel"
  task.FirstRowIsFieldName = "True"
  task.EmptyNumericFieldAsZero = "False"
  task.PerformTask

  Set task = Nothing
End Sub
```